# Parse data before sending it to action link or artificial POST request

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form and it have `action="http://anotherhost.com"`. But I have a problem, before sending it to another host I need to save entered data to database and here is a problem, how to do it?

I have idea, but don't know how to realise it.
1) Change `action="http://anotherhost.com"` to my site, parse entered data and add into database, but then after this I need to simulate artificial POST request to another host.
2) First parse it with JS (AJAX) and after parsing it, let to send form to another host.

Comment: 2nd option is the usual way to go. Notice, though, that even if this local AJAX request will go through ok, there's a chance that the form submit won't reach the other host.

Comment: validate it and send it server side with curl

Comment: I can't use curl, because user must be redirected to `action link`

Comment: when you submit the form, upload what you need to your own database via ajax and let the form process as normal.

Comment: And then how to pause the form process, when ajax do his work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option is probably the best way to go, something like this should work!

http://jsfiddle.net/7Sq3J/

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    $.post('http://example.net/', $('form').serialize(), function(data){
        // handle returned data in here
    });
});
```

This will use a POST request, and send everything you send in the form to http://example.net/

Comment: Not really what I want. Because I need not just send a POST, but user must be redirected there after POST request, but your example will use POST for main page and send POST to another host. I need to pause form submiting to another host by `"action="link"` and wait while ajax return for example Okey, then script will continue process and user will be redirected to another host link.

Comment: I have updated my post, within the anonymous function you can handle the data returned from the POST request, the form will not submit from the HTML until the anonymous function has finished executing.